# Overriding a .phtml file to remove comparison feature

Tags: magento2, template

I would like to remove the comparison feature from catalog pages. I enabled developer hints for the template and found that the file containing the comparison icons was located at:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/addto/compare.phtml
```

I then went ahead and created a file in my theme directory as follows:

```
app/design/fronted/Whistlefish/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/addto/compare.phtml
```

However there is no difference on the frontend. Assuming I've got the folder structure wrong, but I double checked and it looked ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in wrong phtml, you could found the declaration in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml"/>
```

You need to override that phtml in your custom theme. just copy addto.phtml in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addto.phtml` after that remove or comment compare link.

Remove or comment below line

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product);?>'
        data-role="add-to-links"
        class="action tocompare"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span></a>
```

remove var/cache var/page_cache as well as browser cache before tested otherwise old cache files only get display. it perfectly work I have tested

[screenshot for your easy reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTOY6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove compare feature in catalog page :

Go to our custom theme:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

add below line:

```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc   /page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
         <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
      </body>
  </page>
```

then,

Remove var/*

```
<magento-root> $ rm -rf var/* 

remove  var/cache, var/page-cache, va/generation,var/log,..
```

check it. i hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean Remove var/* ?

Comment: @JoeAinsworth  I update my answer

Comment: I've tried this but to no success. The template hint is showing the file at `/var/www/public/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/addto/compare.phtml`. As per your suggestion I created a file in `/var/www/public/app/design/frontend/Whistlefish/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`. I then used `rm -rf var/* ` but the compare feature was still present.